# How to bind event listener for rendered elements in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, addeventlistener, event-binding

How can I bind an event listener in rendered elements in Angular 2?

I am using Dragula drag and drop library. It creates dynamic HTML but my event is not bound to dynamic HTML elements.

Comment: What are "rendered elements" or "dynamic HTML elements". Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```ts
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('my-element')
                                .addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
}

onClick(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Any manual cleaning needed (`.removeEventListener()`) after destroying the component or will Angular take care of this?

Comment: No, if you register it imperatively, you'll need to remove it imperatively.

Comment: Can we pass any arguments along with `bind` ?

Comment: @Kannan What you pass to `bind` will be available as `this` inside `onClick() { ... }` when it is called, so yes, basically any object can be passed.

Comment: Why do we need to inject an ElementRef into the constructor? Shouldnt a new variable be able to do that?

Comment: A new variable is only a place to store a value and does nothing by itself. Angular checks the constructor parameters of classes it creates instances of (everything with `@Component...` `@Injectable`... or any other of its decorators) and finds matching values in its injector dictionary which it then passes to the constructor.

Comment: It's a small point but likely to catch some out. The selector will of course need a # or a . at the start depending on if it is an id or a class e.g. `'#my-element'` if  `<div id="my-element">`

Comment: Remember to add `implements AfterViewInit` to the class declaration

Comment: I can't seem to be able to remove event listeners. Can someone share a sample of how one can do that.
Currently I have this:
`this.dropArea.addEventListener('dragleave', this.unHighlight.bind(this), false)`

& to remove

`this.dropArea.removeEventListener('dragleave', this.unHighlight.bind(this), false)`

Comment: I'd suggest you assign `this.unHighlight.bind(this), false)` to a variable and use the variable to add and remove, this way you ensure you add and remove the same instance, otherwise `bind()` probably returns a different (new) instance and `remove()` thinks you try to remove something that was never added.

Comment: why are we getting 2 events on single click? one with pointerId as 1 and other as -1

Comment: @PhaneendraCharyuluKanduri it's unclear what's going on. Can you demonstrate in a StackBlitz?

Comment: @MikePoole I've almost gave up on managing to listen to element until I saw your comment! it is important enough to write it as an answer instead of a comment. cheers

Comment: Very glad it helped you @EranKT

Answer (score 44):

In order to add an EventListener to an element in angular 2+, we can use the method [listen](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen) of the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) service ([Renderer is deprecated](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer), so use Renderer2):

> listen(target: 'window'|'document'|'body'|any, eventName: string, callback: (event: any) => boolean | void): () => void

Example:

```
export class ListenDemo implements AfterViewInit { 
   @ViewChild('testElement') 
   private testElement: ElementRef;
   globalInstance: any;       

   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.globalInstance = this.renderer.listen(this.testElement.nativeElement, 'click', () => {
           this.renderer.setStyle(this.testElement.nativeElement, 'color', 'green');
       });
    }
}
```

**Note:**

When you use this method to add an event listener to an element in the dom, **you should remove this event listener when the component is destroyed**

You can do that this way:

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.globalInstance();
}
```

The way of use of `ElementRef` in this method should not expose your angular application to a security risk. for more on this referrer to [ElementRef security risk angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834226/elementref-security-risk-angular-2)

Comment: Is there need to 'un-listen' onDestroy ? Or does Angular take care of it ?

Comment: @MehmetGunacti: Good question. The answer is **YES**, and you should un-listen when ngOnDestroy is called. I'll update the answer with this. just take a reference to ``this.renderer.listen`` like ``globalInstance=this.renderer.listen ...`` and call it after that: ``ngOnDestroy() {this.globalInstance();}``

Comment: @HDJEMAI I really like this answer, but how do we add `#testElement` to the rendered element that's outside our control?

Answer (score 21):

**HostListener** should be the proper way to bind event into your component:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'your-element'
})

export class YourElement {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event) {
     console.log('component is clicked');
     console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to bind an event like 'click' for all the elements having same class in the rendered DOM element then you can set up an event listener by using following parts of the code in components.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor( elementRef: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value) => {
      this.onDrop(value.slice(1));
    });
}

public onDrop(args) {

  let [e, el] = args;

  this.toggleClassComTitle(e,'checked');

}


public toggleClassComTitle(el: any, name: string) {

    el.querySelectorAll('.com-item-title-anchor').forEach( function ( item ) {

      item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
              console.log("item-clicked");

       });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@HostListener('window:click', ['$event']) onClick(event){ }
```

check this below link to detect CapsLock on click, keyup and keydown on current window. No need to add any event in html doc

[Detect and warn users about caps lock is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035330/detect-and-warn-users-about-caps-lock-is-on/55476822#55476822)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

create variable inside the component:

```
onlineStatus: any;
```

inside the ngOnInit()  lifecycle method, you can write what you like and it will be treated like a normal JS canvas

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const updateNetworkStatus = () => {
      const text = window.navigator.onLine ? ' online' : ' offline'
      this.onlineStatus = text
    }
    
    updateNetworkStatus()
    window.addEventListener('offline', updateNetworkStatus)
    window.addEventListener('online', updateNetworkStatus)
  }
```

I made [a video](https://youtu.be/ENw2AL3gCUw) on how to do this on my YouTube channel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way to detect when a child element in Angular is rendered and access it.
I found this on Stack Overflow but don't remember where.

```
  private myElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('mySelector', {static : false}) set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if(content) { // initially setter gets called with undefined
      // debugger;
      this.myElement = content;
    }
  }


<div #mySelector *ngIf="initiallyFalseThenAfterDbResponseIsTrue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will help you addEventListener and touch-related swipes gestures.

```js
import { Component, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  
export class AppbarComponent implements OnInit {
  
    touchstartX:number = 0;
    touchstartY:number = 0;
    touchendX:number = 0;
    touchendY:number = 0;

    @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event']) gesuredZonestart(event:any) {
      this.touchstartX = event.changedTouches[0].screenX;
      this.touchstartY = event.changedTouches[0].screenY;  
    }
    
    @HostListener('touchend', ['$event']) gesuredZoneend(event:any) {
      this.touchendX = event.changedTouches[0].screenX;
      this.touchendY = event.changedTouches[0].screenY; 
      this.handleGesure(); 
    }

    handleGesure() {
      var swiped = 'swiped: ';
      if (this.touchendX < this.touchstartX) {
          console.log(swiped + 'left!');
      }
      if (this.touchendX > this.touchstartX) {
          console.log(swiped + 'right!');
      }
      if (this.touchendY < this.touchstartY) {
          console.log(swiped + 'down!'); 
      }
      if (this.touchendY > this.touchstartY) {
          console.log(swiped + 'top!');
      }
      if (this.touchendY == this.touchstartY) {
          console.log('tap!');
      }
    }
}
```