# Detect and warn users about caps lock is on

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, capslock

How to implement to detecting and warning users when caps lock is on with (or not) tooltip style in typescript (angular 4.2.2)?? Maybe with some keyup events, or like `toUpperCase()` in JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you tell if caps lock is on using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript)

Comment: @Den Isahac I think thats different from JS and TS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write a directive and add a listener. Add it to your component's main wrapper div, so component would get the emits. As soon it receives the event change, trigger the state of a property linked to a label tag. It will help to hide and show with *ngIf, the condition being the response from your listener (via an @Output to the component).

The following displays a message dynamically:

HTML:

```
<div (capsLock)="capsOn=$event">
  <input type="text"  >
  <label *ngIf="capsOn">Caps Locked</label>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[capsLock]' })
export class TrackCapsDirective {
  @Output('capsLock') capsLock = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();

  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const capsOn = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
      this.capsLock.emit(capsOn);
  }
  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const capsOn = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
      this.capsLock.emit(capsOn);
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thqgrr)

Comment: i would to show message when caps lock is on, maybe do it without any styles?

Comment: Why do we include this  event.getModifierState

Answer (score 5):

Detect CapsLock on **click, keyup and keydown** on current window. No need to add any event in html doc

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(){}

ngOnInit() {}

@HostListener('window:click', ['$event']) onClick(event){
 if (event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock')) {
   this.capslockOn = true;
  } else {
   this.capslockOn = false;
  }
 }

@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event){
if (event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock')) {
  this.capslockOn = true;
  } else {
   this.capslockOn = false;
  }
}

@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
 onKeyUp(event){
 if (event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock')) {
  this.capslockOn = true;
 } else {
  this.capslockOn = false;
 }
}

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to just show the message when the field is touched?

Comment: as of now, Its not possible to detect in smartphones using only HTML/JS

Comment: getting this error Duplicate function implementation.ts(2393)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Angular can do this out of the box (AngularJS can).

There are a few libraries that can do this though, it would be worth checking out capsLock ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capslock), [GitHub](https://github.com/aaditmshah/capsLock))

You are able to use an observable to check if the caps lock is enabled and then do you custom stuff

```
capsLock.observe(function (result) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Here is the example from the Github readme: https://rawgit.com/aaditmshah/capsLock/master/demo.html

Comment: maybe detect to keychar? no?

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
onCapsCheck(event: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent) {
    this.capsOn = !!(event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock'));
}
```