# Javascript's scope "this" in Typescript's class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, this

I am trying to change custom icon of video, when video is toggled(Play/Pause).

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 const vdoCont = document.querySelector('.video-player');
 const vdo = vdoCont.querySelector('video');
    vdo.addEventListener('play', () => {
     console.log(this) // Here "this" refers to typescript class
     this.updateVdoIcon(this);
    });
    vdo.addEventListener('pause', () => {
     console.log(this) // Here "this" refers to typescript class
     this.updateVdoIcon(this);
    });
}

updateVdoIcon(videoElment: any) {
    console.log(videoElment); // Expecting this to be video element instead of typescript class
  }
```

I have tried to change arrow functions to JavaScript function, but here I cannot use my "updateVdoIcon" function.

```
vdo.addEventListener('play', function() {
      this.updateVdoIcon(this); // Property 'updateVdoIcon' does not exist on type 'HTMLVideoElement'
});
```

I know I can use anonymous function (shown below) and update icon there, but what if I have lot of code which I want to separate in a function

```
vdo.addEventListener('play', function() {
 this.paused ? console.log('Play icon') : console.log('Pause icon')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the event listener handler is call, it's not called under the scope of the Component. So `this` doesn't return the component, but the control element instead.

You need to bind your listener with `this`.

```
vdo.addEventListener('play', (function() {
      this.updateVdoIcon(this);
}).bind(this));
```

See document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

---

You can make it clearer by separating it to a function call onClick.

```
onClick() {
  this.updateVdoIcon(this);
}

initialize() {
  vdo.addEventListener('play', this.onClick.bind(this));
}
```

---

Or, you can capture `this` as the component and pass to the event listener.

```
let self = this;

vdo.addEventListener('play', function() {
      self.updateVdoIcon(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way, using `ElementRef` you can access the element and then bind the event.

Source code is from the : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41610950/9380944 answer.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('my-element')
                                .addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
}

onClick(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `event.currentTarget` in the callback, which would be your element where you defined the event listener:

```
vdo.addEventListener('play', (event) => {
     this.updateVdoIcon(event.currentTarget);
});
```

In your snippet, the `this` would be the ***lexical*** `this` in the arrow function. It captures the the `this` contextfrom the lexical scope i.e. the class instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
const vdoCont = document.querySelector('.video-player');
const vdo = vdoCont.querySelector('video');
const that = this;
   vdo.addEventListener('play', function(){
    console.log(this) // Here "this" refers to typescript class
    that.updateVdoIcon(this);
   });
   vdo.addEventListener('pause', function(){
    console.log(this) // Here "this" refers to typescript class
    that.updateVdoIcon(this);
   });
```

}

updateVdoIcon(videoElment: any) {
       console.log(videoElment); // Expecting this to be video element instead of typescript class
     }