# angular pass parameters to calling function

Tags: angular, hyperlink, click, parameter-passing

I have hyperlink with id parameter

```
<a [routerlink]="[]" class="someclass" id="12">test</a>
```

In script I add function call to this element by this

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.someclass').addEventListener('click', this.someFunc.bind(this));
```

this is someFunc

```
   someFunc(param){
     console.log('someFunc: '+param);
   }
```

When I run app and press that link I get this in console:

```
someFunc: [object MouseEvent]
```

How can I send 'id' param of hyperlink to that function ?

Trying solution from **Aakash Garg**

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.someclass').addEventListener('click', (e) => this.someFunc(e.target.id));
```

For testing printing out straght:

```
(e) => console.log('test: '+e.target.class) > prints out test: undefined
 (e) => console.log('test: '+e.target.id) > prints out test:
```

Comment: Why did you not simply use `(click)="someFunc()"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.someclass').addEventListener('click', (e) => this.someFunc(e.id));
```

Comment: Answer seems to be the right one, but somehow nothing transfers to the function.

Comment: I've tried directly this
'click', (e) => console.log('test: '+e.target.id)
Nothing prints out. Can u check ?

Comment: (e) => console.log('test: '+e.target.class) > prints out test: undefined
(e) => console.log('test: '+e.target.id) > prints out test:

Comment: Care to explain why you would not use an in-built feature of angular but rather work around it?

Comment: you didn't gave id to your element.

Comment: @Philipp Meissner , sorry Philipp but I make html component dinamically with calls to backend , with asincron, with safeHTML and etc etc etc...

Comment: console log e? what's in e?

Comment: 'click', (e) => console.log('test: '+e) gives > [object MouseEvent]

Comment: do it in chrome? or print while json.stringify it?

Comment: in chrome. made straight alert(). gives the same test: [object MouseEvent]

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(e));

Comment: console log e.id

Comment: {"isTrusted":true}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609937/how-to-bind-event-listener-for-rendered-elements-in-angular-2

Comment: I've analysed the e and got the right path
e.path[1].id this is what I wanted. Thanks for your solution, works perfect!

Answer (score -1):

You can use an [angular click-handler](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events). Adding event listeners the way you did has the problem that it may run outside of angular zone and cause problems.

```
<a [routerlink]="[]" class="someclass" (click)="someFunc('12')" id="12">test</a>
```