# How to add mouseover event to a dynamically generated html element by using setAttribute in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I actually want to add **(mouseover)="sample()"** to some html elements which are generated dynamically when the page loads in the browser

I tried to add the **mouseover** to the html element by using

```
const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.className = "highlight";
  span.setAttribute('mouseover', "showToolTip()");
```

by executing the above code, the **mouseover** has been added to the dynamic html element in this way :

```
<span mouseover="showToolTip()">First item</span>
```

But as I'm using angular  I need to wrap the **mouseover** event with parenthesis, which should look like

```
<span (mouseover)="showToolTip()">First item</span>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using native templates injected in the DOM, angular will not parse these parts and discover the directive for the mouseover event.
I would suggest adding the native [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) event instead like so

```
const span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = "highlight";
span.addEventListener("mouseover", ( event ) => {
   console.log(mouseover,event);
   this.showToolTip();
});
```

Edit: After some discutions in the comments we made a more complete solution for OP. [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nativetextonover?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: span.addEventListener("mouseover", ( event ) => {
        "showToolTip(1)"
     });

Comment: But that didnt work @Simplicity's_Strength

Comment: Two things important here, the callback needs to be an arrow function to preserve the "this" reference. Also did you use the quotes there ? This callback should be 
span.addEventListener("mouseover", ( event ) => { this.showToolTip(1); });

Comment: Updated the answer with the function call, i hope it helps @cheesyprogrammer

Comment: I did use the quotes at first. Now I have used what you have commented above and it still doesnt work @Simplicity's_Strength

Comment: Will need more context to help you as there must be something else in this issue that's not mentioned here, try creating a minimal reproducible example with a https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pjzbzm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html     here is my stackblitz. select text to see the inner html in console.log.  In the innerhtml I couldnt bring the mousehover event  @Simplicity's_Strength

Comment: Perfect , so first we need to add the event when we receive the text not on every click.
And used template parsing to add event dynamicaly. Please take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nativetextonover?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You have put in so much effort thanks but you didnt understand my question I guess. In my inner html i.e the variable text i need to insert the (onmouseover)=showToolTip(1) wherever there is span tag with class highlight. That was the question @Simplicity's_Strength

Comment: And that's what we are doing, although i split the mouseover into mouseenter and mouseleave to give more control over showing and hiding the tooltip. when inserting into the div's innerHtml we use div.querySelectorAll(".highlight").forEach(...) to add an event listener onto all spans with class highlight. I beleive you can adapt the current solution to your needs as it does the trick

Comment: See after we do your code, if we were to check the innerhtml contents of  text it should be like this <span class="highlight" (onmouseover)=showToolTip(1) ></span>  and not like this  <span class="highlight" ></span>  @Simplicity's_Strength

Comment: As i said in the original response, using the event binding (mouseover) is a strict synthax that is only valid inside angular templates, but here we are on native html so adding  (onmouseover)="showToolTip(1)" would not add the event listener as angular internaly parses the template and does exactly what we are doing here addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{...}) in it's template parsing.

Comment: Found a similar question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/41610950/4217907

Comment: So your saying its impossible. You could have said that firstitself. Okay I am accepting ur answer as u put in so much effort but personally it didnt work for me @Simplicity's_Strength

Comment: Sorry we didn't understand each other, i thought you wanted to add event listeners on native html templates, this is what the stackblitz does.
Have a nice day sir

Comment: yeah you too @Simplicity's_Strength